# Updating with Morphia Optimistic locking

Tags: java, mongodb, concurrency, morphia, optimistic-locking

Hi considering the following example:

**Resource:**

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
public Response update(@PathParam(value = "id") final String id, final Person person) {
    final Person person = service.getPerson(id);
    final EntityTag etag = new EntityTag(Integer.toString(person.hashCode()));
    // If-Match is required
    ResponseBuilder builder = request.evaluatePreconditions(etag);
    if (builder != null) {
        throw new DataHasChangedException("Person data has changed: " + id);
    }
    service.updatePerson(id, person.getName());
        ....
    }
```

**Service:**

```
public void updatePerson(final String id, final String name) {
    final Query<Person> findQuery = morphiaDataStore.createQuery(Person.class).filter("id ==", id);
    UpdateOperations<Person> operation = morphiaDataStore.createUpdateOperations(Person.class).set("name", name);
    morphiaDataStore.findAndModify(findQuery, operation );
 }
```

**Person:**

```
 @Entity("person")
 public class Person {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private String name;
  ...
 }
```

I do check if the etag provided is the same of the person within the database. However this check is been done on the resource itself. I don't think that this is safe since the update happens after the check and another thread could have gone threw the check in the meantime. How can this be solved correctly? Any example or advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Morphia already implements optimistic-locking via @Version annotation.

http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/annotations/#version

> @Version marks a field in an entity to control optimistic locking. If the versions change in the database while modifying an entity (including deletes) a ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown. This field will be automatically managed for you – there is no need to set a value and you should not do so. If another name beside the Java field name is desired, a name can be passed to this annotation to change the document’s field name.

I see you have already use the annotation in your example. Make sure the clients include the version of the document as part of the request so you can also pass it to morphia.

Not sure if `findAndModify` will be able to handle it (I would think it does). but at least I'm sure `save` *does* handle it.

Assuming the object `person` contains the new name and version that the client was looking at, you can do directly something like this to update the record:

```
morphiaDataStore.save(person);
```

If there was another save before this client could pick it up the versions will no longer match and a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be issued with this message:

`Entity of class %s (id='%s',version='%d') was concurrently updated`